# Spring boot @JoinCulumn ManyToOne relationship column does not exist

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-security

I currently have a problem with this Relationship, I have tried everything I saw on the internet. Still, I get this error:  **ERROR: column roles0_.user_id does not exist.**

I have a boot app that has spring security, and I need to login using users from PostgreSQL database.

But I just can't get the relation between the user and the Role to work.

Here are Entity classes:

```
 @Data
@Entity
@Table(name="user",schema = "public")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Role> roles;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="role",schema = "public")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name="role_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

      @ManyToOne()
   @JoinColumn(name ="user_id")
   private User user;
}
```

The database looks fine, I looked at the column names, etc. I don't know what to do to get rid of this error. I have the user table, and another table named roles, which include id and name, 2 inputs, USER and ADMIN...

It seems  that the @JoinColumn annotation requires one additional column in the roles table the one with @ManytoOne relation, because when I add the column the error disappears, but when I'm trying to get the role from each user, I get an empty List. The foreign key is set as well, from the roles column to the role_id column from role table.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me this way:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "users")
public class User{

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private List<Role> roles;

}
```

and then in roles just:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role{

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = LAZY)
private List<User> users;

}
```

that's if you are ok with third table user_roles (user_id, role_id) which manages the many to many relation

Comment: I actually had a many to many relation, and my point is to get from that to one to many. I managed to get it done by adding a third column in the roles, with the user_id... I don't know if it is a good practice, I think that actually I still have a many to many relation, but with two tables.

Answer (score 0):

User table :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Role> roles;
```

Role table :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```